# Pass a String in Python to a String in C#

Tags: c#, python, string

I know the title sounds a little weird, but I'm wondering if there is a good way to pass a string value in python to a string value in c#?

I have a neural-network that I am using in python to detect objects in an image. For each object that is detected, it also gets an identifier of what the neural-network thinks it detected which is stored in a string. I also have a C# application that I am creating, that runs my Python script through a bat file. What I want to do is get the string identifier from my Python script so I can use it as a string in my C# application. I've though about using a txt file where I would output the string from my Python script and have my C# application read the txt back. Is there any better ways to achieve this out there?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipc.html

Comment: better? better how? what is wrong about you current ways of doing things? that works isn't it? what are you looking for.

Comment: @sommmen If I use a txt file then that's another file I have to work with, both writing to it and reading it back in the respective languages that I am using. I'm wondering if there is a way that I could just pass a python string strait into a c# string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your string as a command line argument to the .net program (e.g. `myprog.exe`)

Then read it out with `Environment.GetCommandLineArguments`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/

if you need to do communication back and forth the easiest way to achieve that is by using a TCP/UDP client/server. The are available in c# and python. There are other mechanisms like named pipes on windows but tcp is the easiest.

This actually has a good sample you could use, but google around;
[Send Data from [Python Client] to [C# Server] using Socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185293/send-data-from-python-client-to-c-server-using-socket)

This is called inter process communication btw, which is a great google term.
Also see:

[What is the simplest method of inter-process communication between 2 C# processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528652/what-is-the-simplest-method-of-inter-process-communication-between-2-c-sharp-pro)